# In django, Is there a way to restrict user access to a url and all its children urls?

Tags: django, django-views

I am writing a simple Django application. I have an index page and accounts section, the account section can only be seen if the user is logged in.

The problem is, that account section have many 'child' urls, like /accounts, /accounts/create, /accounts/update, /accounts/home etc etc.

Currently, i am using login_required decorator and some other tests, but the code looks messy when i write the mixins and decorators on every view.

Is there a simple way to block a url and all its children for a user?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index_view,name="index"),

    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'
    ,form_class=forms.AuthenticationForm), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/',views.SellerRegister.as_view(),name="register_seller"),
    path('accounts/address_create/',views.address_create,name="address_create"),
    path('accounts/register_buyer/',views.register_buyer,name="register_buyer"),

]
```

Comment: You can use @login_required decorator right above the method view.

Answer (score 0):

Login required decorator should work here.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/example url you want redirect/') #redirect when user is not logged in
def myview(request):
    do something
    return something #returns when user is logged in
```

You can also just use the decorator in your urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .views import VoteView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="secret.html"))),
    (r'^vote/', permission_required('polls.can_vote')(VoteView.as_view())),
)
```

If you're using CBV you can try using Permission Mixins.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

Comment: I said i am already using it, i just don't want to repeat that same line over all my views. 
Am wondering if there's a simpler method to just block users from 'accounts' and all urls starting with 'accounts'. 
The views for all the children urls are different.

Comment: Are you using class based views or method based views?

Comment: @MazharAli I edited my answer, see if you find anything helpful from these examples.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but I'd probably search to solve that with a middleware, roughtly:

**settings.py**

```py
LOCKED_PATH = [
    'example/',
]
```

**some_app/middleware.py**

```py
from django.conf import settings


class PathLockerMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        print("Before view is called")
        uri = request.get_full_path()
        user = request.user
        is_authenticated = user.is_authenticated
        print("uri:", uri)
        print("user:", user)
        print("is_authenticated:", is_authenticated)
        # if the request.user is not authenticated and
        # the request.get_full_path() starts with one of the LOCKED_PATH in settings,
        # raise PermissionDenied()

        # else, view is called:
        response = self.get_response(request)

        print("After view is called")

        return response
```

And of course add your middleware in the settings.py, in MIDDLEWARE.
It is just a quick answer, I haven't tried.